# In Postman Flows, how do you create a record with a list of other records, using inputs

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I am learning to use Postman Flows, and I came across an issue that I couldn't find the answer for.

I do some requests and retrieve data, then I want to combine that date into a record that I can use to send in another request. I found out that I could use a Template block for that. So I created a template something like this:

```
"string1": "{{input1}}",
"listOfRecords": {{input2}}
```

I connected a string field to input1 and a list of records to input2, but what I got from that was a string with HTML encoded quotes, like "[{&quot;fieldA&quot;:&quot;value1&quot;...etc.},...etc.]"

I tried different things to have it place the list as a normal list of records, but I could not get that to work. I hope someone can help me figure this out.

For the rest I liked Flows a lot, one annoying thing though that It's not possible to use the CollectionVariables from flows, but that's for a different topic :-)

thanks,

Rogier